# How to sort s list of strings in python ignoring digits in those strings?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, sorting, digits

I would like to sort a list of strings in python, however  digits included in those string should be omitted by the sorting script. Example of such list can be found below:

list = ['aaa', '1aaa', 'abc', '2abc', '3abc', 'b2bb', 'b3bb']

I have found one topic on stackoverflow, namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058455/sort-list-of-names-in-python-ignoring-numbers), but this did not answer my question.
After more research I have found this [page](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/), but my implementation does not work:

```
import re 

def numbers_sort(file):
    lines = []
    lines += [line for line in open(file).readlines()]
    print(''.join(sorted(lines,  key=lambda key: [x for x in re.sub('^[-+]?[0-9]+$', '')])),end="")
```

I have been also trying to use isdigit() as key of the sorted function, however for no avail.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key-Argument expects a function, that convert one string.

```
def numbers_sort(filename):
    with open(filename) as lines:
        print(''.join(sorted(lines,  key=lambda s: re.sub('[-+]?[0-9]+', '', s))), end="")
```